# Algorithm: Find out which objects hold the subset of input array

Tags: algorithm, set, subset, union

We have some objets (about 100,000 objects), each object has a property with some integers (range from 1 to 20,000, at most 20 elements, no duplicated elements.):

For example:

- object_1: `[1, 4]`
- object_2: `[1, 3]`
- object_3: `[100]`

And the problem is, we input a array of integer (called A), find out which objects hold the subset of A.

For example:

- when `A = [1]`, the output should be `[]`
- when `A = [1, 4]`, the output should be `[object_1]`
- when `A = [1, 3, 4]`, the output should be `[object_1, object_2]`

---

The problem can be described in python:

```py
from typing import List


# problem description

class Object(object):

    def __init__(self, integers):
        self.integers = integers

    def size(self):
        return len(self.integers)


object_1 = Object([1, 4])
object_2 = Object([1, 3])
object_3 = Object([100])


def _find_subset_objects(integers):  # type: (List[int]) -> List[Object]
    raise NotImplementedError()


def test(find_subset_objects=_find_subset_objects):
    assert find_subset_objects([1]) == []
    assert find_subset_objects([1, 4]) == [object_1]
    assert find_subset_objects([1, 3, 4]) == [object_1, object_2]
```

---

Is there some algorithm or  some data struct is aim to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Is it one integer per document and user, or one per permission per document and user? What I'm really asking is: are the permissions implemented as bit-flags?

Comment: There is no user in fact, just permissions. And the permissions is auto increment integer. I'm ready to modify the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Since these are permissions, we can assume that each object is a set - e.g. the contained elements are unique. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The contained elements are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the objects in an array. The indices will be 0 ... ~100K. Then create two helper arrays.

- First one with the element counts for every object. I will call this array **obj_total**(This could be ommited by calling the object.size or something similar if you wish.)
- Second one initialized with zeroes. I will call it current_object_count.

For every integer property **p** where 0 < **p** <= 20000, create a list of indices where index **i** in the list means that the element is contained in the i-th object.

It is getting messy and I'm getting lost in the names. Time for the example with the objects that you used in the question:

```
objects = [[1, 4], [1, 3], [100]]
obj_total = [2, 2, 1]
current_object_count = [0, 0, 0]
object_1_ref = [0, 1]
object_2_ref = [ ]
object_3_ref = [1]
object_4_ref = [0]
object_100_ref = [100]
object_refs = [object_1_ref ,object_2_ref , ... , object_100_ref]
#Note that you will want to do this references dynamically.
#I'm writing them out only for the sake of clarity.
```

Now we are given the input array, for example [1, 3, 4]. For every element **i** in the array, we look we look at the **object_i_ref**. We then use the indices in the reference array to increase the values in the **current_object_count** array.
Whenever you increase a value in the `current_object_count[x]`, you also check against the `obj_total[x]` array. If the values match, the object in `objects[x]` is a subset of the input array and we can note it down.

When you finish with the input array you have all the results.

Comment: Thank you Shamis! A nice solution.  And I implemented your solution in [gist](https://gist.github.com/Kxrr/6b18401a77d5ad51a2df42cb257b6462)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Please consider accepting the answer :-). If a better one comes along the way, you can always accept that one instead.